# ExpandableListView Group indcator changed to point UP in Android 4

Tags: android, expandablelistview

I use an ExpandableListView in my app.  In all previous (< 4) versions of Android, the icons for the Groups either pointed to the right (collapsed) or down (expanded).
In Android 4, the icon points Down for collapsed, and Up for Expanded.
This is bizarre.

How can I get the old behavior back?

Answer (score 1):

in your expandable listview xml set:

```
 android:groupIndicator="@drawable/settings_selector"
```

and create a selector like this:

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
   <item android:drawable="@drawable/up_arrow" android:state_empty="true"/>
   <item android:drawable="@drawable/down_arrow" android:state_expanded="true"/>
</selector>
```

this references to some of your own drawables ... you can also use androids drawables with

```
android:drawable="@android:drawable/....."
```

Comment: Thanks, after all that management decided that we aren't going to change it back. (can never seem to make up their mind...)